# Is this INNER JOIN the equivalent of using IN?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

The following set of queries is taking about 15ms to complete, which is too long for me, so I want to optimize it.

```
INSERT INTO @tabl (Id) 
   SELECT [Value] 
   FROM dbo.Split(@Ids,',');

SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tblOther WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @tabl));
```

Basically, it splits the value of `@Ids`, which is a comma-delimited list, and places it into a table variable. Then it searches another table for any records with an `Id` in this list of `Ids`. This seems like it is very inefficient to me, and I thought that an `INNER JOIN` could accomplish the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO @tabl (Id) 
   SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.Split(@Ids,',');

SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
              FROM tblOther AS t 
              INNER JOIN @tabl AS s ON s.Id = t.Id)
```

In both sets of queries, I get the same result, but I'm wondering if this is just because of my data, or if it is because these are functionally equivalent.

Using the `INNER JOIN` completes 4x faster than using `IN`. I assume this is because `IN` is checked against each row.

#### Questions

1. Are these two sets of queries functionally equivalent where the function is to return all rows who have an `Id` in `@tabl`?
2. Is there a faster alternative that I haven't considered?

Comment: Where is `@Ids` coming from? One obvious optimization is if you could change the caller to pass a table-valued parameter in the first place, if at all possible.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's coming from a classic ASP page that passes a comma delimited string to a stored procedure, which then calls the function that this code resides within. I don't think you can pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure in classic ASP, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I think your second block of code is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your first block of code.  If the number of rows in @tabl is much smaller than tblOther, you could test your own assumption by transforming the first query to;

```
INSERT INTO @tabl (Id) select [Value] FROM dbo.Split(@Ids,',');
SET @Count = (SELECT count(1) from @tabl WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM tblOther));
```

Comment: Thanks. I did have a typo in the first block. `@tabl` is much smaller than `tblOther`. This is a good idea - testing it now.